# VBA - Change MS Word Font Style Based on Excel Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, ms-word

I want to automatically change a document’s font type and size based on Excel cell values. For example, if I input “Times New Roman” in cell B3 and 12 in cell B4, then the document should be formatted with these styles. However, when I run my macro, it ignores my variables and I can’t figure out why.
Below is my code:

```
Sub FormatWholeAsDefaultFont()
    Dim mySpreadsheet As Excel.Workbook
    Dim strFont As String, strRange As String
    Dim sngFontSize As Single, sngTopMargin As Single, _
        sngBottomMargin As Single, sngLeftMargin As Single, _
        sngRightMargin As Single
    Set mySpreadsheet = _
           GetObject("C:\Files\Data\Excel\Document Timesheet.xlsm")
    
    strFont = mySpreadsheet.Application.Workbooks("Document Timesheet.xlsm") _
            .Sheets("Document Agreement").Range("B2").Value
    sngFontSize = mySpreadsheet.Application.Workbooks("Document Timesheet.xlsm") _
            .Sheets("Document Agreement").Range("B3").Value
    sngLeftMargin = mySpreadsheet.Application.Workbooks("Document Timesheet.xlsm") _
            .Sheets("Document Agreement").Range("B5").Value
    sngRightMargin = mySpreadsheet.Application.Workbooks("Document Timesheet.xlsm") _
            .Sheets("Document Agreement").Range("B6").Value
    sngTopMargin = mySpreadsheet.Application.Workbooks("Document Timesheet.xlsm") _
            .Sheets("Document Agreement").Range("B7").Value
    sngBottomMargin = mySpreadsheet.Application.Workbooks("Document Timesheet.xlsm") _
            .Sheets("Document Agreement").Range("B8").Value
    strRange = mySpreadsheet.Application.Workbooks("Document Timesheet.xlsm") _
            .Sheets("Document Agreement").Range("B9").Value
    'strFont = CStr(strFont)
    Selection.WholeStory
    With ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font
        .Name = strFont
        .Size = sngFontSize
        .Italic = False
        .Underline = wdUnderlineNone
        .UnderlineColor = wdColorAutomatic
        .StrikeThrough = False
        .DoubleStrikeThrough = False
        .Outline = False
        .Emboss = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Hidden = False
        .SmallCaps = False
        .AllCaps = False
        .Engrave = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .Spacing = 0
        .Scaling = 100
        .Position = 0
        .Kerning = 11
        .Animation = wdAnimationNone
        .Ligatures = wdLigaturesNone
        .NumberSpacing = wdNumberSpacingDefault
        .NumberForm = wdNumberFormDefault
        .StylisticSet = wdStylisticSetDefault
        .ContextualAlternates = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your interest. The macro is in Word, referencing  Excel. I used the same code to set margin sizes and it worked, but not for font style or size. When I hover my mouse over strFont and sngFontSize it displays the correct respective results, though.

Comment: What is the font name and size of the Normal style in the active document before and after running your code?

Comment: Let's ignore the part where you get the font name and size from the spreadsheet. Will your code work properly if you hardcode the font name/size?

Comment: Thank you for your follow-up question. Font size and type varies from document to document, which is what gave me the idea of standardizing them from Excel. My test document Normal is Arial 11.

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried setting .Name = "Times New Roman" and .Size to 12, and it did not work. What do you suppose happened?

Comment: Please define "it did not work". Do you get an error? Does the font name and size for the Normal *style* change (please check the style definition **not** the text in the document)? If the font settings of the text in your document didn't match the Normal style to begin with (i.e. font has been set directly from the ribbon), changing Normal won't affect anything

Comment: To clarify, the macro ran without error, but it did not change the font or size, ignoring the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of unnecessary code in your routine. Below is a simplified version.

```
Sub FormatWholeAsDefaultFont()
    Dim mySpreadsheet As Excel.Workbook
    Dim strFont As String, strRange As String
    Dim sngFontSize As Single, sngTopMargin As Single, _
        sngBottomMargin As Single, sngLeftMargin As Single, _
        sngRightMargin As Single
    Set mySpreadsheet = _
        GetObject("C:\Files\Data\Excel\Document Timesheet.xlsm")
    
    With mySpreadsheet.Sheets("Document Agreement")
        strFont = .Range("B2").Value
        sngFontSize = .Range("B3").Value
        sngLeftMargin = .Range("B5").Value
        sngRightMargin = .Range("B6").Value
        sngTopMargin = .Range("B7").Value
        sngBottomMargin = .Range("B8").Value
        strRange = .Range("B9").Value
    End With
    
    With ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font
        .Name = strFont
        .Size = sngFontSize
    End With
End Sub
```

**Please note:**

Since Word 2007 it has been necessary to set the document's default font in the Set Defaults tab of the Manage Styles dialog, accessed from a button at the bottom of the Styles pane or by typing `Dialogs(wdDialogStyleManagement).Show` into the Immediate Window. It is vital for the correct working of Table Styles that the Normal style match these document defaults.

***However, it is not possible to set the document defaults using VBA.***

Comment: I'm new to macros, so thank you for simplifying my code. When I ran your version, it did not update the font and style, but when I added "Selection.Font.Name = strFont and "Selection.Font.Size = sngFontSize" it changed the format successfully. Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: @SingleMaltScott - I suspect that the code *did* change the style, but  the text in the document *didn’t* change because it didn’t match the style in the first place. Directly applying formatting, whether in code using `Selection`, or by selecting content and using the controls on the ribbon, is ***not*** a good thing to do. It adds complexity to the document and makes it difficult to see where formatting is coming from, as you have already discovered. What you need to do is format the document correctly, using styles. Then it will be easier to change formatting properly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, and I hope I understood you correctly. I removed "Select.Font.Name" and  "Select.Font.Size", and moved "Selection.WholeStory" below "ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font" With loop. I then added "Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")" below WholeStory. Am I on the right track or did I inadvertently repeat the incorrect way of formatting a document? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @SingleMaltScott - yes that is correct. Word is designed to be used with styles. Any additional formatting is applied over the style, which results in additional xml being generated for each paragraph, or run of text, the formatting is applied to. This quickly ramps up the file size and can lead to corruption. In your code always use the enum for built-in styles, e.g. `wdStyleNormal`. This will ensure your code works in non-English language versions of Word where style names are localised.

Comment: That did it. Thanks again for everything!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FormatWholeAsDefaultFont()
    Dim mySpreadsheet As Excel.Workbook
    Dim strFont As String, strRange As String
    Dim sngFontSize As Single, sngTopMargin As Single, _
        sngBottomMargin As Single, sngLeftMargin As Single, _
        sngRightMargin As Single
    Set mySpreadsheet = _
        GetObject("C:\Files\Data\Excel\Document Timesheet.xlsm")
    
    With mySpreadsheet.Sheets("Document Agreement")
        strFont = .Range("B2").Value
        sngFontSize = .Range("B3").Value
        sngLeftMargin = .Range("B5").Value
        sngRightMargin = .Range("B6").Value
        sngTopMargin = .Range("B7").Value
        sngBottomMargin = .Range("B8").Value
        strRange = .Range("B9").Value
    End With
    
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Font.Name = strFont
    Selection.Font.Size = sngFontSize
    
    With ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font
        .Name = strFont
        .Size = sngFontSize
    End With
End Sub
```